# How can i get value from span through jQuery?

Tags: jquery

i need to access **The Title of Something** through jQuery which is in span.

```
<span class="checkbox">
    <input name="item_add" value="1234" type="checkbox"> The Title of Something, </span>
```

can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you show us the html and what you tried?

Comment: i have tried to access to access the span through  jQuery.text() , but it chages the  check box to the text that i use.  but i am unable to access the "the title of something" @liora

Comment: Please show us how you tried to use `jQuery.text()`

Comment: if you only want to access the text, you must put the text alone in it's own span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have any inner text or inner html from input elements. They are empty elements. They have no closing tag. You have to create a span to reach the text you want beneath input tag.

```
<span class="checkbox">
 <input name="item_add" value="1234" type="checkbox">
  <span id="textSpan">
    The title of something
  </span>
</span>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function{
   var text = $('#textSpan').text();
   //you have the inner text now.You can change it like this.
   $('#textSpan').text()= "new text";
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `text()` on the `<span>`

```js
var txt = $('.checkbox').text().trim()

console.log(txt)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="checkbox">
    <input name="item_add" value="1234" type="checkbox"> The Title of Something, </span>
```